# ECharts: Multiple series (lines) with own yAxis

Tags: echarts

I want to switch from Highcharts to ECharts (preferably 3), but my current graphs have multiple series ('lines' in my case), with each their own yaxis, and it seems ECharts doesn't support this.

[image]

These metrics do not relate at all, so they all need their own yaxis. I combine them in 1 chart so they can be compared relative to each other (500 visits, €30000, 3% conversion.. etc). It makes no sense to plot 500 visits and 3% conversion rate on the same yaxis.

Is there a way to give each line it's own yaxis? It doesn't have to be a visible one (since there can only be two with ECharts, left/right of canvas, and that's ok), but the data needs to be plotted to an individual axis.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
 yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      name: 'left_yaxis',
      nameTextStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      },
      splitLine:{
        show:false,
      },
      axisLabel: {
        textStyle:{
          color:'#fff',
        }
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'value',
      name: 'right_yaxis',
      nameTextStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
      },
      axisLabel: {
        interval:'0',
        textStyle:{
          color:'#fff',
        }
      },
      splitLine: {
        lineStyle: {
          color: ['#454545'],
        }
      },
      min:0,
      //max:800000,
      splitNumber:5
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Also if you find your axis overlapping, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831620/javascript-echarts-multiple-y-axis-overlapping-each-other

Comment: code only comments do not help people understand what the fix is for the problem.

Comment: a code example is worth a thousand words

Answer (score 5):

Here ar example from echarts for dual y axis:

- [example 1](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=mix-line-bar)
- [example 2](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=multiple-y-axis)

Comment: I was missing yAxisIndex in the second series. This example clearly shows that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more than one y axis in echarts by making yaxis element as a array

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ECharts supports multi-axis. See example at [ECharts Gallery](http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/editor.html?c=area-rainfall).